# Understanding implications

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have a set of questions where to task is to add the correct implication arrow.

I was able to make sense of most of them, but for two problems, I can't figure out why I was wrong.

Here is what I put:

| Statement $S1$ | Statement $S2$ | I answered | The answer in the book is |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\frac{x}{x+1} = 0$ | $x=0$ | $S1\iff S2$ | $S1 \Rightarrow S2$ |
| $(a,b)$ is a point on the line $y=2x-1$ | $b=2a-1$ | $S1 \iff S2$ | $S1 \Rightarrow S2$ |

For the first one, I can't see how when $x=0$, $\frac{x}{x+1}$ can equal anything other than $0$, so surely the implication works both ways? I presume I'm missing something obvious.

For the second, the point $(a, b)$ is on line $y = 2x -1$, so $b$ must equal $2a - 1$. Again I presume I've missing something here.

Really would appreciate any help here, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: For me, both answers that you selected are correct

Comment: You are correct and your reasoning is as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'But the correct answer is $\Rightarrow$'?

Comment: Maybe your conclusion 'the correct answer is-->' is not right. What is true is, 'a correct answer is -->', so maybe when you read it somewhere the reverse direction was not important, so it wasnt stated. There are a lot of true implications which are never explicitly stated.

Comment: @Hermis14 Sorry, I ought to have been clearer - I'll add an edit in to clarify. I mean that is the answer in the back of the book that I'm using.

Comment: Check out the errata page (maybe online) for that book. Also which book (and edition) is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one:

Sufficiency ($\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $x/(x+1) = 0$. This expression already assumes $x\neq -1$. So we can multiply it with $x+1$ to get $x = 0$. (True)

Necessity ($\Leftarrow)$: Suppose $x = 0$. It is a trivial result that $x/(x+1) = 0$. (True)

Therefore, the first one is an N-S condition.

Second one:

In set-builder notation, 'the point is on the line' if and only if
$$
(a,b) \in \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~y = 2x -1\}
$$
and it is *equivalent* to say that $b = 2a - 1$ given that $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ due to [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#3._Axiom_schema_of_specification_(also_called_the_axiom_schema_of_separation_or_of_restricted_comprehension)).
That is, the second one is also an N-S condition.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer - certainly clarifies things for me!

Comment: @OliverRadini I am glad to hear that! Consider marking this as a selected answer.

Answer (score -2):

The symbols represent the direction of the implication. It means you can read back and/or forwards substituting by "then". The one with two arrows is "similar" to the equivalence symbol.

In the first, x = 0 does not imply only that x/(x+1)=0, but much other expressions. The same for the line.

Strictly speaking, the statement has a direction which must be rigidly read.

Comment: You'd better rethink this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wonder if you could expand it to clear a few things up, I'm still not sure from this answer how $x=0$ does not imply that $x/(x+1) = 0$

Comment: It means. But x = 0 could mean also x^2 = 0. The solution is not unique. Hence, it would be better if you use the unidirectional arrow.

Comment: Is that how implication works? I can't imagine there are many statements that do not have multiple implications, surely though it wouldn't stop any given one of those statements being true?

Comment: An advice: reduce the number of negatives in your sentence. It may help you with proofs and mathematical statements.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto good advice I'm sure, but that isn't the problem I'm concerned with here. I want to learn more about how to construct proofs, and without further clarification your answer is likely, I believe, to be unhelpful to anyone who might read it.